# How do I set up a datastream for sale?

Tags: data-marketplace, sales, data

So, [datum.iota.org](http://datum.iota.org) is offering access to data streams? Is there any way I could sell my data through the same network at this time?

Answer (score 6):

The sensors currently on the network are from the participating companies.

Public contribution will be available somewhere in December:

[image]